# Block StackNavigator move back

Tags: react-navigation

How can we block a move back event of stacknavigator on required page. I navigate from loginpage incase login succeed to homepage. But there if we goback using navigation('home'); it shows the previous login form with input data by the user.

How can we restrict react-navigation stacknavigator not to move back or how to release the dom array present in the stacknavigator ?

I declare navigator like this ;

```js
const navig = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: homescreen,},
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
  api:  { screen: apipage},
  cabdetails:  { screen: cabdetails},
  loginRegister: {screen: loginReg,},
  picklocale:{screen: pickmap})
```

Answer (score 0):

Know that it is old, but you can use next helper function at your login/register screen:

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
...
handleResetNavigationToRoute = (routeName) => {
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: null,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName})
        ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
};
```

And change

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')

with

> this.handleResetNavigationToRoute('Home')

After that changes you can't move backwards to login/register screen.

```
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21" - used
```